# jQuery - Multiple items with hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, jquery-animate

In CSS I have several DIV items with hover effects. If I hover on an element the one element has another background color. If I hover over another item the previous selected item has the default background color without hovering.

How can I do this with jQuery? I want to animate the background color but want to disappear the fade (animate) effect with hovering on another item. I tried it with window timeout but after sliding the mouse pointer over a few elements everything is flickering and bugging.

This is the code I used for the animation effect on mouse over:

```
$('.entry').mouseover(function() {
 (this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#0F410E" }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
});
```

jQuery Colors plugin is installed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

Please flick the code of jsfiddle I will take a look but try this:

I not sure what is the reason of using `queue and duration` I reckon you know `:)` hence you are using it.

Hope it help the cause.

```
var items = '.entry'
$(items).hover(function() {
    // Mouseover state
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#0F410E" }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
}, function() {
    // Mouseout state
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
});
```

Comment: You have to put items into $() brackets: $(items). Then it works for all elements.

Comment: @thonixx Glad it helped `:)` funny thing is I got downvoted lol Random `:)` oh and good edit indeed!

Answer (score 1):

for animating `background-color` of an element as jQuery natively doesn't animate the colors, you should use [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin.

> This plugins installs a `cssHook` which allows jQuery's `.animate()`to animate between two colors.

Comment: jQuery Colors plugin is installed ;)